# What is wrong with my paramerized mysql statement in c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

When I try to execute this, I get an exception saying the syntax is incorrect?

```
string sql= string.Format(@"SELECT valueA
                      FROM tableA
                      WHERE columnA = @columnValueA");


        var parameters = new MySqlParameter[1];
        parameters[0] = new MySqlParameter("@columnValueA", string.Format("{0}","abc"));


foreach (var mySqlParameter in parameters)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(mySqlParameter.ParameterName, mySqlParameter.Value);
}

//later I execute, it tells me the syntax is incorrect

-- I am trying to execute something on the database similar to below

SELECT valueA
FROM tableA
WHERE columnA = "abc"
```

Comment: Is `columnA` actually a string column?  If it's a numeric column you should be providing the parameter value as an integer, not as a string representation of an integer.

Comment: @Servy - It is a string, for non-string values, I am not using string.Format.

Comment: Did you try explicitly casting the parameters to `Object`? `AddWithValue` expects objects.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My query is correct, essentially, what was happening nested deeply within the code was it was appending an extra `)` which was rendering the query syntax incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

do you need @ in the MySqlParameter string? I would imagine you could do without it?

Comment: Which @ are you referring to?  They are in multiple places.